# How to retrieve data from Dynamics 365 using QueryExpression in Azure Function App?

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, azure-functions, dynamics-365

I want to retrieve all accounts from Dynamics 365 CRM using QueryExpression in Azure Function App. Is this possible or any other way to do so ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Possible but not a binding provided out of the box today. You’d need to leverage the Dynamics 365 Rest API or SDK within the Function and authenticate/call yourself. The other option is leveraging Logic Apps + Functions which does have an option to list all records from Dynamics 365 with an Odata query and return a result set that could be passed into a Function.